# The action can't be completed because the file is open in coldfusion.exe

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm running ColdFusion 10.282462 Standard running on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I'm making changes and renaming various ColdFusion .cfc files.  However, when I try to rename a .cfc file, I often get

```
File In Use 
The action can't be completed because the file is open in coldfusion.exe
Close the file and try again.
```

How can I get coldfusion.exe to close the file? It seems to stop happening after several minutes, but I'd like to move faster than that...  I tried "Clear Template Cache Now" and "Clear Component Cache Now" in the CF Administrator.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to restart the CF service to release the files

Comment: Release the files from what though? I have never seen this issue.

Comment: Rather odd. ColdFusion would only ever be looking at those files when it needs to compile them, which should only be once each time they are requested after the file has been updated. I've never seen this happen before.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, stop the ColdFusion service before renaming your files. Honestly I have not seen that before. Are the `.cfc` files that you are renaming registered as web services?

Comment: I have seen it when a file is opened, but there is a crash before the file is closed

Comment: Yes did you all figure out how to release the files? I ran a cfexecute and created an output file (test.txt) that I am unable to delete because it says its running in the coldfusion.exe